# How to limit the length of a tag?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm using the default taxonomy tags with nodes. If users forget to enter the commas to separate the words it will generate one really long tag.

What's a good way to do a validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use hook_form_alter for this to add custom validation to core forms

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

Create a form_alter_hook in your module and add a validation function to the taxonomy field in your form:

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == "<your contenttype>_node_form") {   
        $form['#validate'][]='yourmodule_taxonomy_length_check';
    }
}
```

Then just create a validation function to implement your logic, ex:

```
function yourmodule_taxonomy_length_check($form, &$form_state) {
    if (strlen($form_state['values']['<taxonomy_field_name>']) > <your value>) {
        form_set_error('<taxonomy_field_name>', 'Term is too long');
    }
}
```

For your taxonomy_field_name, you want to use the 'name' value of the taxonomy field in your target content type.

Answer (score 1):

thank you schnippy for the detailed example.

For future reference the code I used is:

```
function yourmodule_taxonomy_length_check($form, &$form_state) {
  $tags = $form_state['values']['field_disc_tags']['und'];
  foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if ((strlen($tag['name']) > 15) || (substr_count($tag['name'], ' ') > 1)) {
      form_set_error('field_disc_tags', 'Please enter tags separated by commas');
    }
  }
}
```

The tags are in an array and I'm checking to make sure no tag is longer than 15 characters or has more than 1 space in it.